# hibernate.cfg.xml not found - NHibernate + dot.net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, nhibernate

I'm creating a simple console app to test the nhibernate 5.2.7 using the .net core 3.1.

I just add a App.config to my project:

[image]

That is my App.config file content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=NHCookbook;persist security info=True;user id=smo;password=smo;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string_name">db</property>
      <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

That is my main method and the NHibernate configuration:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
    var sessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
    Console.WriteLine("NHibernate Configured!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

When I run this console application, The follow exception is thrown:

> `Exception: NHibernate.Cfg.HibernateConfigException: 'An exception occurred during configuration of persistence layer.'`
>
> `Inner: FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'D:\@git\stufs\Cookbook\ConfigByAppConfig\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\hibernate.cfg.xml'.`

The exception is throw in the follow statement:

```
var nhConfig = new Configuration().Configure();
```

csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NHibernate" Version="5.2.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="App.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Never</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Remark**

If I try to configure the Nhibernate by code it works properly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nhConfig = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
    {
        db.Dialect<MsSql2012Dialect>();
        db.ConnectionStringName = "db";
        db.BatchSize = 100;
    });

    var sessionFactory = nhConfig.BuildSessionFactory();
    Console.WriteLine("NHibernate Configured!");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Go to your hibernate.cfg.xml

in the properties, find build action, and set its type to **content**, and the copy to output directory to **Copy Always**

[image]

Comment: Thank you in advanced. I'm not using hibernate.cfg.xml, All my configuration is over the app.config and from what I know hibernate.cfg.xml is not necessary in this case.